# SystemJS, Typescript, angular2 and modularity

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm trying to write basic app with angular2/systemjs/typescript with modularity that i used with angular1, and have some problems.
I need this thing anywhere in my app without depending on the relative location of files, where `smth-module` is any module that i wrote and contains(exports) `SmthCmp` class

```
import SmthCmp from 'smth-module';
```

Test app sctructure

```
├── bootstrap.ts
├── graph-module
│   ├── component
│   │   └── line-graph
│   │       └── line-graph.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── page-module
    ├── component
    │   └── page
    │       └── page.ts
    └── index.ts
```

**bootstrap.ts**

```
...
import {PageCmp} from 'page-module/index';

bootstrap(PageCmp, [
  ...
]);
```

**page.ts**

```
...
import {LineGraphCmp} from 'graph-module/index';

...
export class PageCmp {}
```

**line-graph.ts**

```
...
export class LineGraphCmp {}
```

graph and page modules **indexes** like this

```
export {PageCmp} from './component/page/page';
```

also added to **System.config()**

```
map: {
    'graph-module': '/graph-module',
    'page-module': '/page-module'
}
```

So i can use `export Smth from 'module/index'` syntax anywhere and this is almost what i need. But there is one problem

```
app/bootstrap.ts(4,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'page-module/index'.
app/page-module/component/page/page.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'graph-module/index'.
```

How can i tell Typescript compiler about this modules? Or can i achive this modules usage via other way or modules system?
Also can i somehow achive this usage `import {PageCmp} from 'page-module'` without direct '/index' reference?

p.s. this is copypaste from my last question at [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5063)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is totaly about my problem. Waiting for Typescript update with `moduleResolution: 'target'` usage

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039